# Should I say "laundry poles on the veranda" or "laundry poles in the veranda"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Example sentence:

> She was hanging my clothes on the laundry poles on/in the veranda.

By veranda and laundry poles, I mean something like this:

[image]

(Note: for some reason veranda is synoynm with balcony in some Asian countries like Japan.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many a structure can be considered as both a platform and an enclosure. **veranda** is  one of them, and you can say **in** the veranda, though in American English it is far more common to hear *out **on** the veranda*; that is probably because in the US a veranda is an open porch on the ground floor, not a balcony as in your photo.

I can't quite see the photo.  But if those are ropes or cords stretched across the balcony, they would be called **lines** or **clotheslines** not **poles**.

Comment: washing line...

Comment: In my neck of the woods we call them **clotheslines**.  *Your shirt is  hanging out on the clothesline.*

Comment: BrEng, washing line... but still that's a balcony not a veranda - the two sides of the pond can agree on that at least ;)

Answer (score 2):

"On the verandah" is used much more commonly than "in the verandah" ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+verandah%2Cin+the+verandah&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20verandah%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20verandah%3B%2Cc0)) in both British English and US English. I am used to open verandahs, so 'on the verandah' sounds more normal to me. However, I could understand people with enclosed verandahs saying 'in the verandah' instead. So, looking at the picture supplied by the OP, I would be going with 'on the verandah' in this case.